# Random string generation I/O python

Tags: python, string, random

I'm creating a python script which should create a new file every time it generates a new string (everytime the script is executed it prints out the string to file), and also compares this random string with a string which is a text like: `THIS IS A STRING`, which is located on another already created file.

For example, the string `THIS IS A STRING` is located on file called `file.dat`, and the random generated string should be written to a file, in this case I call it `newfile.txt`.

However, I have this code:

```
import string
import random

file = open('file.dat', 'r')
file=file.read()
print file

def id_generator(size=28, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
file = open("newfile.txt", "w")
file.write(id_generator())
file.close()
```

This code, simply reads the `file.dat` archive, prints it to console, then generates a random string and stores it on a file called `newfile.txt`, but it doesn't compares anything, so, to accomplish that I've modified the code like this:

```
import string
import random

file = open('bullshit.dat', 'r')
file=file.read()
print file

def id_generator(size=28, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
with open("newfile.txt", "r") as f: stored = f.readline() 
if stored == id_generator(): 
    print('success!')
```

Now, my problem is, that this code just reads an already created file, which is `newfile.txt`, I need to create a new one like the code I had before, but comparing the strings.

I tried modifying the last three lines like this:

```
with open("newfile.txt", "w") as f: stored = f.readline() 
if stored == id_generator(): 
    print('success!')
```

But it throws me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "string2.py", line 20, in <module>
with open("newfile.txt", "w") as f: stored = f.readline() 
IOError: File not open for reading
```

How can I accomplish something like the first version, but comparing the strings as the second one?

Comment: you have to open the file first

Comment: when using the open call, you are using w flag which means open for writing...see documentation ..https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Comment: Thank You, I know, but what I'm trying to do, is to create the file everytime I run the script so it can be actually random, if I read it, then it is a file somehow created before, so the random code doesn't make any sense, I don't know if my approach is correct to accomplish this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution you had "w" which can only write to the file so you have to open it as "r" which reads it.

```
import string
import random

file = open('test.dat', 'r')
file=file.read()
print file

def id_generator(size=28, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
with open("newfile.txt", "r") as f: stored = f.readline()
if stored == id_generator():
    print('success!')
```

Comment: Thank You very much, but this file should be created, not readed, if I read it, then it is the same file created before, so, should I delete it and run the script again maybe? Just to be sure, thank You. But if I delete then it is not random though.

Comment: Deleting it and rewriting it would be pretty random.

Comment: Thanks for applying my answer. :)